# Subquery of type IN must have only one output column at [4:3]

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `tlp-dataplatform-prod.published_kpi.UCV*`
WHERE (customer_code, _TABLE_SUFFIX) IN (
  SELECT customer_code, MAX(_TABLE_SUFFIX) AS max_suffix
  FROM `tlp-dataplatform-prod.published_kpi.UCV*`
  GROUP BY 1
)
```

this query uses a subquery to first find the maximum _TABLE_SUFFIX for each customer_code using the MAX() function and the GROUP BY clause. The outer query then filters the results to only include the rows where the (customer_code, _TABLE_SUFFIX) pair matches the values returned by the subquery. **This effectively returns only the rows with the maximum _TABLE_SUFFIX for each customer_code, while still selecting all columns from the table.**

But it returns me this error on BigQuery:
"Subquery of type IN must have only one output column at [4:3]"

I tried to change the order of the in but nothing cahnge

Comment: bigquery doesn't support multiple  coluns in an IN clause, use a JOIN instead or an EXISTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this query instead:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `tlp-dataplatform-prod.published_kpi.UCV*` as u1
WHERE  _TABLE_SUFFIX = (
  SELECT MAX(_TABLE_SUFFIX) 
  FROM `tlp-dataplatform-prod.published_kpi.UCV*` as u2
  WHERE u2.customer_code = u1.customer_code
)
```

It checks if `_TABLE_SUFFIX` is maximum for corresponding `customer_code`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery for this, as Big Query doesn't support multiple columns

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM tlp-dataplatform-prod.published_kpi.UCV t1
JOIN ( SELECT customer_code, MAX(_TABLE_SUFFIX) AS max_suffix FROMtlp-dataplatform-prod.published_kpi.UCV* GROUP BY 1 ) t2
ON t1.customer_code = t2.customer_code 
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = t2.max_suffix
```

Comment: In the first FORM is not tlp-dataplatform-prod.published_kpi.UCV* ?

Comment: then you need to move the comparison to t´the where clasue

Answer (score 0):

Another option to get the expected output you need is to use the `QUALIFY` clause with the `rank` function as the following:

```
select * from your_table
qualify rank() over (partition by customer_code order by _TABLE_SUFFIX desc) = 1
```